# Android notification on web site content updation

Tags: android

I am creating a website application. The website is actually coded in php. In the website there is an option to post comments by users who are logged in to the site. Actually I wanted  to show notification on the android device even when the application is not running . Can anyone please suggest an idea for doing this. Should I need to make any permission settings in the website for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android side: Create a Service which polls server update. Server side: implements whatever is needed by the service to be aware of an update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide notifications without a Activity being visible you should use a Service. The service could simply ask your website if an update has been made and if so the service could issue a notification.